# Perform set difference with apach beam

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have two lists `a` and `b` and there are some common elements between them, I want to find those common elements and their count, for which I have wrote the following program.

```
import functools
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.runners.interactive.interactive_runner import InteractiveRunner
from apache_beam.runners.direct.direct_runner import DirectRunner
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

options = PipelineOptions()

p = beam.Pipeline(InteractiveRunner(underlying_runner=DirectRunner()), options=options)

def form_pair(element, side_input):
  for i,e in enumerate(side_input):
    if e == element:
      return i,e


a = ['a','b', 'c', 'c', 'b']
b = ['a','a','b', 'c', 'b', 'b','d', 'e', 'f']

x0 = p | "0" >> beam.Create(a) | "1" >> beam.Distinct()
x1 = beam.pvalue.AsList(x0)


x3 = p | "2" >> beam.Create(b)
x4 = x3 | "3" >> beam.Map(functools.partial(form_pair, side_input=x1))
x5 = x4 | "4" >> beam.combiners.Count.PerKey()


r = p.run().wait_until_finish()

print(r.get(x5))
```

which is giving me the following error

```
TypeError: 'AsList' object is not iterable [while running '3']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was passing the side inputs to `beam.Map` function incorrectly Here is the correct way for that

`x4 = x3 | "3" >> beam.Map(form_pair, x1)` instead of `x4 = x3 | "3" >> beam.Map(functools.partial(form_pair, side_input=x1))` which was wrong.